# how to connect .asmx web service with swift 3.0.

Tags: c#, sql-server, swift, alamofire

Currently i am using Xcode 8 and mac 10 OX EI Captian on a virtual machine.
i am new to ios programming. i am visited many web sites and videos to but i am unable to get answer..

I have configured CocoaPods succesfully but i am not getting the response from web service.. 
**I have hosted my web service to IIS which is working fine**

Code:

```
Alamofire.request("http://192.168.15.24/Service/WebService1.asmx?      op=HelloWorld").responseJSON { response in
            //print(response.request as Any)  // original URL request
            //print(response.response as Any) // URL response
            print(response.result.value as Any)   // result of response serialization
        }
```

Error:

```
2017-03-22 15:59:44.394457 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110233] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-22 15:59:44.401768 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-22 15:59:44.440788 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-22 15:59:44.449202 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 192.168.15.24:80
2017-03-22 15:59:44.450597 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
2017-03-22 15:59:44.451323 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to 192.168.15.24:80
2017-03-22 15:59:44.452847 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fc270c084e0
2017-03-22 15:59:44.453491 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting
2017-03-22 15:59:44.454138 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 192.168.15.24:80 initial path (null)]
2017-03-22 15:59:44.454959 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.15.24:80 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2017-03-22 15:59:44.457818 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1 192.168.15.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)]
2017-03-22 15:59:44.458201 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.15.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
2017-03-22 15:59:44.459033 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.15.24:80 waiting path (satisfied)] skipping state update
2017-03-22 15:59:44.459613 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_proxy_handler_should_use_proxy Looking up proxy for hostname: <nil>, ifindex: 0
2017-03-22 15:59:44.461591 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCPreferences, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2017-03-22 15:59:44.464071 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] [1 192.168.15.24:80 waiting socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-22 15:59:44.465029 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket [1 192.168.15.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] creating socket
2017-03-22 15:59:44.465809 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1 192.168.15.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-22 15:59:44.469743 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2017-03-22 15:59:44.470955 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-22 15:59:44.472302 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.1.8
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010741580e __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001076f2194 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3002
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001076cfdb8 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001076cedd5 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001076cdb34 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001076e8d11 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001076e8740 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107192980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001071bc
2017-03-22 15:59:44.473828 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols [1 192.168.15.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Attached flow protocol
2017-03-22 15:59:44.474225 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.15.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:start_connect
2017-03-22 15:59:44.476577 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x800
2017-03-22 15:59:44.477477 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received CONNECTED event
2017-03-22 15:59:44.478243 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_socket_setup_notsent_lowat Set TCP_NOTSENT_LOWAT(16384)
2017-03-22 15:59:44.479182 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [1 192.168.15.24:80 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
2017-03-22 15:59:44.480464 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1 192.168.15.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-22 15:59:44.481226 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_endpoint_flow_connected_path_change [1 192.168.15.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Connected path is satisfied
2017-03-22 15:59:44.482231 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.15.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:finish_connect
2017-03-22 15:59:44.483043 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110287] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 192.168.15.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] reported event flow:changed_viability
2017-03-22 15:59:44.483965 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110284] [] __tcp_connection_start_block_invoke 1 sending event TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED in response to state ready and error (null)
2017-03-22 15:59:44.484800 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110284] [] tcp_connection_event_notify 1 event: TCP_CONNECTION_EVENT_CONNECTED, reason: nw_connection event, should deliver: true
2017-03-22 15:59:44.486400 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110284] [] tcp_connection_get_statistics DNS: 0ms/0ms since start, TCP: 8ms/28ms since start, TLS: 0ms/0ms since start
nil
2017-03-22 16:00:14.784458 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110321] [] tcp_connection_cancel 1
2017-03-22 16:00:14.785815 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x4
2017-03-22 16:00:14.788211 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received WRITE_CLOSE event
2017-03-22 16:00:14.789584 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1 192.168.15.24:80 ready socket-flow (satisfied)]
2017-03-22 16:00:14.791469 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [1 192.168.15.24:80 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected
2017-03-22 16:00:14.792424 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] -[NWConcrete_tcp_connection dealloc] 1
2017-03-22 16:00:14.793347 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Event mask: 0x1006
2017-03-22 16:00:14.794109 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event Socket received DISCONNECTED event
2017-03-22 16:00:14.794950 NewCocoaPodEnabeling[2959:110491] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_disconnected [1 192.168.15.24:80 cancelled socket-flow (null)] Output protocol disconnected
```